# Should I use "and" in legal documents for lists?

Tags: copyright-notice

> Permission is hereby granted to all parties to copy, distribute copies of this license...

Should I use and here instead, or is omitting it more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence in the question, you should use "and". Otherwise it is ungrammatical and unclear.